# ArgumentOutOfRangeException error Unity3D C# when trying to get a random element from a list after iterating through an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

**Problem:** 
I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error when trying to get a random element from a list after iterating through an array.

**Goal:**
I'm trying to activate a random child game object inside the parent game object by looking for tags. There are multiple child game objects inside parent. If that game object is tagged with the tag I'm looking for, I want to pick it out and add it to new lists based on its tag. Then after iterating through that array, I want to get a random element for each of those new lists and set it active

```
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> heads = new List<Transform>();
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> bodys = new List<Transform>();
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> arms = new List<Transform>();
[SerializeField] private Transform[] bodyParts;

private GameObject head;
private GameObject backpack;
private GameObject arm;

void Start()
{
    bodyParts = this.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (bodyParts[i].tag)
        {
            case "Head":
                heads.Add(bodyParts[i]);
                break;

            case "Arm":
                arms.Add(bodyParts[i]);
                break;

            case "Backpack":
                backpacks.Add(bodyParts[i]);
                break;

            default:
                Debug.Log("Not relevant");
                break;
        }
    }
    SetActiveBodyPart(heads, head);

    SetActiveBodyPart(arms, arm);

    SetActiveBodyPart(backpacks, backpack);
}

void SetActiveBodyPart(List<Transform> whichBodyParts, GameObject whichBodyPart)
{
    if (whichBodyParts != null)
    {
        whichBodyPart = whichBodyParts[Random.Range(0, whichBodyParts.Count)].gameObject;
        if (!whichBodyPart.activeSelf)
        {
            whichBodyPart.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    else Debug.Log("Nothing here...");
}
```

I'm getting error at this line:

**whichBodyPart = whichBodyParts[Random.Range(0, whichBodyParts.Count)].gameObject;**

When I deactivate all of my child game objects inside parent by hand and start the game, those lists in Unity editor return 0 but i expect the output will be positive integers

Comment: You don't currently check if the list is empty. So if there are 0 objects in whichBodyPart, you will attempt to index into it, and any index is invalid.

Comment: I thought I already had it here at " if (whichBodyParts != null) "

Comment: *if (whichBodyParts != null && whichBodyParts.Count > 0)*

Comment: It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code.

Comment: @Bezari0us That only checks if the list doesn't even exist, which is important to do, but a list can exist and also have zero elements.  You should do `if (whichBodyParts != null && whichBodyParts.Count > 0)`

Comment: `if (whichBodyParts?.Any() == true)` will check for both null and that it contains something.

Comment: So i tried to add `whichBodyParts.Count > 0` and yes it is not throwing me any error, but instead it threw me `Nothing here...`. Seems like I have something to do with the code above. As far as I understand, because I included `bodyParts = this.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();` and also set all child objects to be deactivate. Maybe that 's the problem

Comment: The upper bound is inclusive, so `Random.Range(0, 1)` can return 1, which of course is an out of range index for a list of 1 item.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, `Random.Range(0,1);` will never return 1. The upper bound of `Random.Range(int, int)` [is exclusive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html).

Comment: @Ruzihm ah, that's different for the float overload. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include deactivated components in the results of [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html), you need to include the `includeInactive` parameter and set it to `true`. Also, putting `this.gameObject` before `GetComponentsInChildren` is redundant:

```
bodyParts = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
```

To handle the situation where you get empty lists anyway, you should also include a check that avoids indexing into empty lists:

```
if (whichBodyParts != null && whichBodyParts.Count > 0)
{
    whichBodyPart = whichBodyParts[Random.Range(0, whichBodyParts.Count)].gameObject;
    if (!whichBodyPart.activeSelf)
    {
        whichBodyPart.SetActive(true);
    }
}
else Debug.Log("Nothing here...");
```

Comment: ...`GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true)` is brilliant! I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you aren't checking to see if there are any items in the list before you try to access one. You can check for items using the `Count` property, or the `Any` extension method, and if we combine this with the null-conditional operator (which will return `null` if the object on the left is `null`), we can do:

```
void SetActiveBodyPart(List<Transform> whichBodyParts, GameObject whichBodyPart)
{
    if (whichBodyParts?.Any == true)
    {
        whichBodyPart = whichBodyParts[Random.Range(0, whichBodyParts.Count)].gameObject;

        if (!whichBodyPart.activeSelf)
        {
            whichBodyPart.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log("Nothing here...");
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to check for each condition separately if you want to have more accurate information in your logs:

```
void SetActiveBodyPart(List<Transform> whichBodyParts, GameObject whichBodyPart)
{
    if (whichBodyParts == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("whichBodyParts is null");
    }
    else if (!whichBodyParts.Any())
    {
        Debug.Log("whichBodyParts does not contain any items");
    }
    else
    {
        whichBodyPart = whichBodyParts[Random.Range(0, whichBodyParts.Count)].gameObject;

        if (!whichBodyPart.activeSelf)
        {
            whichBodyPart.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```